# Custom webform component for displaying a list of nodes

Tags: webforms

I would like to have a content-type with *Add to cart* button that would allow a user to add current node to the cart. Then there would be a webform that would list all the items (nodes) that the user added to the cart.

Can anyone give me directions on how to achieve this? I think it has something to do with creating custom webform component.

Comment: If you're looking to create an ecommerce kind of site, look into [Drupal Commerce module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. My solution was to add a 'Add to Cart' button on the node which stores that node to the session. I created a new webform component based on textarea that is readonly and lists all nodes that the user added.